# CSS rollover 1 div and another div changes

Tags: css, hover, rollover

What my client wants is when you hover over the light orange it changes to the dark orange, which is easy, but when you get to the center of the button and hover over the dark orange it turns to the light orange (this is what I am having a hard time with.. Please advise

[image]

```
<a href="#"><div class="buttonblue">
<div class="buttontitle">local businesses</div>
<div class="buttonaction_blue">NEXT</div>
<div class="buttonsmallprint">Leverage online</div>
</div></a>
```

css

```
.buttontitle { 
 font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: 0;
 padding:4px 0px 4px 0px;
 font-size:36px; 
 color:#fff;
 text-align:center;
 } 
 .buttonaction_blue:hover
  {
    background-color:#418dc7
  }  
  .buttonaction_blue 
 {
  width:355px; 
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:#4795d1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif; 
  font-size:32px; 
  text-align:center;  
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px 0px 10px 0px; 
  }
```

Comment: Show how you have done up to now. Live example.

Comment: [link]http://vldir.com/stackoverflow/h1.html

Comment: The blue one works fine for me, but the orange one has no rollover.

Comment: your question is about orange one and you provided the code of blue one.

Comment: Oh my bad.... either way they both need to do something.. the solution would be the same for either one..... had the orange one cut out..... the blue one I want the holder to change color when you rollover the buttonaction div... is that possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're just trying to stack :hover on the divs:

http://jsfiddle.net/tSZ2u/1/

```
.buttonaction_blue:hover {
     background-color:#5BCAE9
}

.buttonblue:hover {
     background-color: #4795d1;
}
```

If adding a hover to both the bluebutton and buttonaction_blue solves the issue, great. If not, there is no CSS selector for an item's parent (at this time). You'll need to look into some jQuery using .parent(): http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: yah thats exactley what Im trying to do... but when I get to the center div is there a way to get the holder to switch colors so its solid light blue?

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll need to use some jQuery to do this -- there is no parent selector in CSS (.buttonblue < .buttonaction_blue or .buttonaction_blue:parent don't exist). You can write some code to use the .parent selector in jquery though.

Answer (score 0):

You said

```
"What my client wants is when you hover over the light orange it changes to the dark orange"
```

If you want light orange(which is blue in your example i.e. provided) change to dark and no change in the dark orange then replace this

```
.buttonaction_blue:hover
{
background-color:#418dc7
}
```

with

```
.buttonblue:hover
{
background-color:#5BCAE9;
}
```

or If you want light orange(which is blue in your example i.e. provided) change to dark and dark orange changes light orange then just add this

```
 .buttonblue:hover
{
background-color:#418dc7;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J9yhf/)